# Haskell type class for Queue

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Has anyone written a Haskell type class (or is there a combination of type classes) that describes a FIFO queue.

[Data.Collection.Sequence](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/collections-api/1.0.0.0/doc/html/Data-Collections.html#g:6) seems too strong, but on the other hand [Data.Collection.Unfoldable](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/collections-api/1.0.0.0/doc/html/Data-Collections.html#g:2) seems too weak (as order is not defined).

I just wanted to not redo someone else's work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's actually not too hard (and an interesting exercise) to roll your own FIFO queue in Haskell. I can appreciate your wanting to use a standard typeclass for this, and that's almost certainly what you should do. But I just learnt about this last week, and I'm too excited not to write about it.

Here's a simple queue class, that allows you to check whether the queue is empty, to get the first element from the head of the queue (and return the rest of the queue) and to insert a new element into the queue.

```
class Queue q where
  empty :: q a -> Bool
  get :: q a -> (a, q a)
  ins :: a -> q a -> q a
```

The simplest way to make a FIFO queue is using a list:

```
instance Queue [] where
  empty = null

  get []     = error "Can't retrieve elements from an empty list"
  get (x:xs) = (x, xs)

  ins x xs = xs ++ [x]
```

However, this is horribly inefficient. If the queue currently has *n* elements, then inserting a new element takes O(*n*) time. If you want to insert *m* elements into an empty queue, that takes O(*m*<sup>2</sup>) time. Can we make a queue that inserts and retrieves elements in O(1) time (or at the least, O(1) amortized time)?

The trick is to store the front and back of the queue in separate lists, with the back of the queue being stored in reverse:

```
data Fifo a = F [a] [a]

instance Queue Fifo where
```

The queue is empty if both the front and the back are empty:

```
  empty (F xs ys) = null xs && null ys
```

To insert a new element into the list, we just cons it onto the back queue, which takes O(1) time.

```
  ins y (F xs ys) = F xs (y:ys)
```

Getting an element from the front of the queue is easy when there are elements waiting there (and we throw an error if the queue is empty)

```
  get (F []     []) = error "Can't retrieve elements from an empty queue"
  get (F (x:xs) ys) = (x, F xs ys)
```

Finally, if there are no elements waiting at the front of the queue, then we reverse the back of the queue and put it at the front. Although this takes O(*n*) time, we only have to do it once for each element, so our get operation averages out to O(1) time:

```
  get (F [] ys) = get (F (reverse ys) [])
```

There you have it - amortized O(1) FIFO queues in a functional language.

---

**Edit:** Efie asked about the amortized O(1) performance in the comments. The argument for amortized constant time is pretty simple.

Consider a sequence of *n* insertions to an empty queue, followed by *n* retrievals. The insertions take time *n*. On the first retrieval, the front of the queue is empty, so we have to reverse the back of the queue, which also takes time *n*, plus 1 to retrieve the element. finally, the next *n* - 1 retrievals take time 1 each, so the total time is

*n* + *n* + 1 + *n* - 1 = 3 *n*

We made 2 *n* calls in total, so the amortized time is 3 *n* / 2 *n* = 3/2, which is O(1). The same argument works no matter how the calls to `ins` and `get` are interleaved - in two calls, each element is cons'ed once, moved once and de-cons'ed once.

Comment: Thank you, I like your post. To avoid getting an error, you have to check if the list is null every time before you 'get' an element, haven't you? Is this better than changing the type of get to get :: q a -> (Maybe a , q a)?

Comment: The 'safe' way would be to change the type to `get :: q a -> Maybe (a, q a)` (with the `Maybe` wrapping the tuple, since it doesn't make sense to return the rest of the queue if we've failed to retrieve the first element). I ignored this to keep the implementation simple, so with my code you have to check if the list is null before you can safely use it. Note that this isn't any more work, since with the `Maybe` wrapper we'd have to check for `Nothing` *after* the call instead. However, with the wrapper we are forced by the type system to check - without it, you can write unsafe code.

Comment: I'd like to expand on how the average case of getting an element is only O(1). If you have n elements in your queue, there are (n+1)! ways to allocate them to two lists: n! ways to arrange n elements, (n+1) ways to divide each arrangement into two lists. There are n! ways to arrange elements in ys if xs is empty. The number of : operations now is composed as follows: prob("xsIsEmpty")*costs("xsIsEmpty")+prob("xsNotEmpty")*costs("xsNotEmpty) = n!/(n+1)! * n + ... * 0 = n/n+1 = O(1).

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what operations you want to have. The [queuelike](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/queuelike/1.0.9/doc/html/Data-Queue-Class.html) and [dequeue](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/dequeue/0.1.5/doc/html/Data-Dequeue.html) packages have type classes for queues.